# Exceptional electromagnetic properties of lanthanide series elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements, rare-earth-elements

**Why do so many lanthanide series elements have exceptional electromagnetic properties?** They can form strong magnets and are also used in superconducting applications. The number of elements in the lanthanide series displaying these properties is far higher than other blocks in the periodic table

One thought is that these properties arise as a result of the magnetic moment of the atoms themselves: filling up the f-orbital contributes to both angular orbital momentum as well as spin orbital momentum. Is this speculation correct?

**References:**

> Another important use of neodymium is as a component in the alloys used to make high-strength neodymium magnets—powerful permanent magnets.

[Neodymium - Wikipedia, the Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium)

> Europium becomes a superconductor when it is cooled below 1.8 K and compressed to above 80 GPa. This occurs because europium is divalent in the metallic state,[8] and is converted into the trivalent state by the applied pressure.

[Europium - Wikipedia, the Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium)

> Samarium doping of iron-based superconductors – the most recent class of high-temperature superconductors – allows enhancing their transition temperature to 56 K, which is the highest value achieved so far in this series.

[Samarium - Wikipedia, the Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium)

Comment: I think it'll be difficult to find a good answer that encompasses superconductivity, because there are still important gaps in our theoretical understanding of high-temperature superconductors.

Comment: Also, many of the key properties (for both superconductivity and magnetism) are dependent on the bulk properties of the solids or alloys containing the element and not just the properties of the individual atoms. That makes any explanation much more complex.

Comment: A simplistic answer may indeed be the open f-shells. The relativistic effects should not be ignored, either.

Comment: @TAR86 Relativistic effects, to my knowledge, are only significant for the 6th period elements and below eg. Gold, Cerium, Mercury and Tungsten.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I believe that the lanthanides are 6th period elements, and cerium is one of the lanthanides.